# autocompleteselect and foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner under django, I currently work on an application to record births
the father key of the birth class points to the registration table that records fathers and mothers

in my form.py file, the father field is an autoselectfield.
And that's my problem:
the autoselectfield returns an id while the father field must point to an object of type registration

how can i return the object linked to the id.
as long as the father field does not point to an object I will not be able to register a new birth in the base

Thank you in advance

my view.py

```
class EntityCreateView(CreateView):

def form_invalid(self, form, error_msg="Erreur lors de la sauvegarde."):
    messages.error(self.request, self.request.POST)
    return super(EntityCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form, success_msg="Enregistrement réussi."):
            # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
            # It should return an HttpResponse.
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            messages.success(self.request, success_msg)
            #father_id = form.cleaned_data['father']
            form.father = Registration.objects.get(id=form.father)
            return super(EntityCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

class BirthCreateView(EntityCreateView):
    template_name = 'eregister/birth_detail.html'
    model = Birth
    form_class = BirthForm

    def get_initial(self):
            if 'from_external_page' in self.kwargs and 'birth_post_form' in self.request.POST:
                    # If we added a birth or a person, we want to restore the initial form
                    birth_post_form = self.request.session['birth_post_form']
                    del self.request.session['birth_post_form']
                    return birth_post_form
            return super().get_initial()


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            """Called after the get method"""
            # Call the base implementation first to get a context
            context = super(BirthCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            birth_form = context.get('form')
            birth_form.initial['language'] = Language.get_default_language()
            return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
            #self.father = Registration.objects.get(father_id=form.father)
            father_id=self.cleaned_data['father']
            father = get_object_or_404(Registration, pk = father_id)
            sel.cleaned_data['father'].update(father)
            super(BirthCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
            birth_id = self.object.id
            # Automatically propose to create the first copy of the book
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('eregister:bc_add', args=[birth_id]))
```

forms.py file

```
 class CommonForm(forms.ModelForm):
required_css_class = 'required'

 class BirthForm(CommonForm):

    class Meta:
            model = Birth
            exclude = ['social_number', 'created']

    firstname = forms.CharField(label=Meta.model._meta.get_field('firstname').verbose_name,
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '50'}))

    father = AutoCompleteSelectField('father_list', label=Meta.model._meta.get_field('father').verbose_name,
            required=False, help_text=None, plugin_options={'autofocus': True, 'minlength': 3})

    mother =  AutoCompleteSelectField('mother_list', label=Meta.model._meta.get_field('mother').verbose_name,
            required=False, help_text=None, plugin_options={'autofocus': True, 'minlength': 3})

    sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.RadioSelect,choices= SEX_CHOICES)
    birthday = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today())


    def clean_fathers(self):
            if self.cleaned_data['father']:  # It is a list
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please select at least one author"))
            return self.cleaned_data['father']

    def clean_mothers(self):
            if not any(self.cleaned_data['mother']):  # It is a list
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please select at least one publisher"))
            return self.cleaned_data['mother']
```

models.py

```
  class Birth(ModelEntity):

    firstname       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex             = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthweight     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,  decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Poids à la naissance")
    birthday        = models.DateField(null=False, verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthhour       = models.TimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Heure de naissance')
    birthcity       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry    = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Pays de naissance', default='Bénin')
    father          = models.ForeignKey(Registration, related_name='father', verbose_name='Father',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    mother          = models.ForeignKey(Registration, related_name='mother', verbose_name='Mother',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    mairie          = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Mairie')
    social_number   = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, verbose_name='numero social', unique=True)
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    objects = BirthManager()


    def __str__(self):
            return "%s - %s - %s - %s %s - %s - %s" % (self.firstname, self.sex, self.birthweight, self.birthday,
                                                    self.birthhour,self.birthcity, self.birthcountry)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created']
            verbose_name= ("Naissance")
            verbose_name_plural = ("Naissances")
```

Comment: Hello everyone,
After checking the autocomplete returns the object, but I still do not understand why I can not register in the database, no error is returned, suddenly I do not know where to look.

Comment: Hi Patrick.  Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: really sorry for the delay, yes it's resolved